# Why does Java's StringJoiner merge method copy over delimiters?

Tags: java, string

Suppose I have the following code

```
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringJoiner SJ1 = new StringJoiner(", ");
        StringJoiner SJ2 = new StringJoiner("* ");

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
            SJ1.add(Integer.toString(i));
            SJ2.add(Integer.toString(i + 5));
        }

        System.out.println(SJ1);
        System.out.println(SJ2);

        SJ1.merge(SJ2);
        System.out.println(SJ1);
    }
}
```

The first print statement produces the string 1, 2, 3, 4

The second print statement produces the string 5* 6* 7* 8* 9

The third print statement (merge operation) produces:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5* 6* 7* 8* 9

Why is merge simply performing a concatenation of two string ? I would expect the merge operation to output 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

I'm having trouble understanding why this method exists and what the design choices behind it were ? I don't see any practical application of this.

Comment: The method exists because it can be very useful, assuming you're using *consistent* joiners. `StringJoiner` doesn't remember all the elements that went into it using the `add()` method. It performs the concatenation continually, so there is no way to replace the delimiter already applied. Its not meant to, and you're using it wrong. If you want to build two sequences of strings, then merge them later, and not decide on delimiter until the end, use `List` and `addAll()` to merge them, then `StringJoiner` at the end to build the final string.

Comment: I’m not a thought reader, but I might suppose the rationale behind `merge()` is that it’s handy for merging two string joiners that have the same delimiter. IMHO the behaviour you have observed is clearly documented, so ought not be surprising (except `SJ1` ought to contain a 0 too).

Comment: It's to merge two `StringJoiner`s with the _same delimiter_ in the first place.